# Multiple subscriptions to Observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I create my own `Observable` and subscribed two functions to it. I would expect to have both functions executed for each element in the sequence but only the last one is.

```js
let observer = null
const notificationArrayStream = Rx.Observable.create(function (obs) {
  observer = obs;
  return () => {}
})

function trigger(something) {
  observer.next(something)
}

notificationArrayStream.subscribe((x) => console.log('a: ' + x))
notificationArrayStream.subscribe((x) => console.log('b: ' + x))

trigger('TEST')
```

Expected output

```
a: TEST
b: TEST
```

Actual output

```
b: TEST
```

Here's the JSBin: http://jsbin.com/cahoyey/edit?js,console

Why is that? How can I have multiple functions subscribed to a single `Observable`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To have multiple functions subscribe to a single Observable, just subscribe them to that observable, it is that simple. And actually that's what you did.

BUT your code does not work because after `notificationArrayStream.subscribe((x) => console.log('b: ' + x))` is executed, `observer` is `(x) => console.log('b: ' + x))`, so `observer.next` will give you `b: TEST`.

So basically it is your observable creation which is wrong. In `create` you passed an observer as parameter so you can pass it values. Those values you need to generate somehow through your own logic, but as you can see your logic here is erroneous. I would recommend you use a subject if you want to push values to the observer.

Something like:

```
const notificationArrayStream = Rx.Observable.create(function (obs) {
  mySubject.subscribe(obs);
  return () => {}
})

function trigger(something) {
  mySubject.next(something)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Subjects were the missing link. For future reference: http://jsbin.com/wifokoc/edit?js,console

Comment: "because after (...) is executed observer is `(x) => console.log('b: ' + x))`" why ? could you elaborate a bit more or show reference, please ?

Comment: okay, found reference [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subscribing-to-observables)

Answer (score 92):

### Subject

In your case, you could simply use a `Subject`. A [subject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md) allows you to **share a single execution with multiple observers** when using it as a proxy for a group of subscribers and a source.

In essence, here's your example using a subject:

```
const subject = new Subject();

function trigger(something) {
    subject.next(something);
}

subject.subscribe((x) => console.log('a: ' + x));
subject.subscribe((x) => console.log('b: ' + x));

trigger('TEST');
```

Result:

```
a: TEST
b: TEST
```

---

#### Pitfall: Observers arriving too late

Note that the timing of when you subscribe and when you broadcast the data is relevant. If you send a broadcast before subscribing, you're not getting notified by this broadcast:

```
function trigger(something) {
    subject.next(something);
}

trigger('TEST');

subject.subscribe((x) => console.log('a: ' + x));
subject.subscribe((x) => console.log('b: ' + x));
```

Result: (empty)

---

### ReplaySubject & BehaviorSubject

If you want to ensure that even future subscribers get notified, you can use a [ReplaySubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/replaysubject.md) or a [BehaviorSubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md) instead.

Here's an example using a `ReplaySubject` (with a cache-size of 5, meaning up to 5 values from the past will be remembered, as opposed to a *BehaviorSubject* which can remember only the last value):

```
const subject = new ReplaySubject(5); // buffer size is 5

function trigger(something) {
    subject.next(something);
}

trigger('TEST');

subject.subscribe((x) => console.log('a: ' + x));
subject.subscribe((x) => console.log('b: ' + x));
```

Result:

```
a: TEST
b: TEST
```

Comment: I really wish the basic RXJS tutorial would mention subjects (i.e. more than in passing when comparing to event emitters with little explanation) - without them working basic use cases degrade into non-working use cases at the first sign of complication. It really looks like the RXJS guide was written for people who already know RXJS (or written under the false assumption that developers looking for a solution to a problem will stay to read a 20-page guide).

Answer (score 12):

Every time you subscribe, you are overriding the var *observer*.

The *trigger* function only reference this one var, hence no surprise there is only one log.

**If we make the var an array it works as intended:** [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/zizisoweva/edit?js,console)

```
let obs = [];

let foo = Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
  obs.push(observer);
});

function trigger(sth){
//   console.log('trigger fn');
  obs.forEach(ob => ob.next(sth));
}

foo.subscribe(function (x) {
  console.log(`a:${x}`);
});
foo.subscribe(function (y) {
  console.log(`b:${y}`);
});

trigger(1);
trigger(2);
trigger(3);
trigger(4);
```

A cleaner solution would be to use [Subject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject), as suggested above.

Comment: This is the real answer.

Answer (score 5):

Observables are not multicasting; unless you use any kind of `Subject`. You can of course create Subject, pipe the `Observable` output into like other answers propose.

However if you **already have** an `Observalbe`, it is way more convenient to use `share()` that turns `Observable` into `Subject` or `shareReplay(n)` which would be equivalent for `ReplaySubject(n)`:

```
import {share} from 'rxjs/operators';

let observer = null

const notificationArrayStream = new Observable(obs => {
  observer = obs;
}).pipe(share());

function trigger(something) {
  observer.next(something)
}

notificationArrayStream.subscribe((x) => console.log('a: ' + x))
notificationArrayStream.subscribe((x) => console.log('b: ' + x))

trigger('TEST')
```

That's pretty much it.

Answer (score 0):

You can build wrapper class Subscribable<> based on ReplaySubject. It would be cleaner than managing Subject and Observable:

```
export class Subscribable<T> {

    private valueSource: Subject = new ReplaySubject(1);
    public value: Observable;
    private _value: T;

    constructor() {
        this.value = this.valueSource.asObservable();
    }

    public set(val: T) {
        this.valueSource.next(val);
        this._value = val;
    }

    public get(): T {
        return this._value;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let arrayStream : Subscribable<TYPE> = new Subscribable<TYPE>();

…
public setArrayStream (value: TYPE) {
    this.set(value);
}
```

Handle value change:

```
arrayStream.value.subscribe(res => { /*handle it*/ });
```

Original article: http://devinstance.net/articles/20170921/rxjs-subscribable

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Subject, it is also possible to use the [publishReplay() + refCount() combo](https://blog.kaush.co/2015/01/21/rxjava-tip-for-the-day-share-publish-refcount-and-all-that-jazz/) to allow an observable to multicast to multiple subscribers:

```
const notificationArrayStream = Rx.Observable.create(function (obs) {
  observer = obs;
  return () => {}
}).pipe(publishReplay(), refCount())
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const subs = []

const ob = new Observable((s) => {
  console.log('called')
  subs.push(s)
})

const trigger = (v) => {
  subs.forEach((sub) => {
    sub.next(v)
  })
}

ob.subscribe((v) => {
  console.log('ob1', v)
})

ob.subscribe((v) => {
  console.log('ob2', v)
})

trigger(1)
```

Change your code into something like this, and it will work. The point here is that each subscription is updated through its corresponding subscriber, if you have multiple subscriptions, you have to notify multiple subscribers. And in your case, you just notified the last one.